# Retrieving only the ETag for a range of bytes in an object

Tags: etag

Does the Google Storage REST API support generation and retrieval of ETag values for an arbitrary range of bytes with an object? For e.g., I uploaded an object of 100MB and got the ETag for the full object. Great. At a later date, I'm interested in only the ETag that would result over the range, say, 10-20MB of that object. The objective is to query for the ETag that would result if there were an object only made up of the bytes that reside in the specified range without retrieving the bytes in question. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

As long as it is the identical entity the `ETag` should be identical for range requests. I.e. the ETag is not depended on the requested range.